# Streaming large json file to csv

Tags: json, stream, jq

I have a large JSON file contains a list of objects like this:

```
{
   "_index":"pelias",
   "_type":"address",
   "_id":"jf808cdawi46z",
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "center_point":{
         "lon":106.66307,
         "lat":10.959882
      },
      "name":{
         "default":"375/20 Bùi Quốc Khánh, Chánh Nghĩa, Bình Dương, Việt Nam"
      }
   }
}
{
   "_index":"pelias",
   "_type":"address",
   "_id":"jf808cdawi46z",
   "_score":1,
   "_source":{
      "center_point":{
         "lon":106.66307,
         "lat":10.959882
      },
      "name":{
         "default":"375/20 Bùi Quốc Khánh, Chánh Nghĩa, Bình Dương, Việt Nam"
      }
   }
}
```

I'm using jq to convert it to a csv like this:

```
"address","lat","lon"
"375/20 Bùi Quốc Khánh, Chánh Nghĩa, Bình Dương, Việt Nam",10.959882,106.66307
"375/20 Bùi Quốc Khánh, Chánh Nghĩa, Bình Dương, Việt Nam",10.959882,106.66307
```

I'm using this code:

```
cat pelias_minify.json | jq -r -s '. | [.[]  | {lat: ._source.center_point.lat, lon: ._source.center_point.lon, address: ._source.name.default}] | (map(keys) | add | unique) as $cols | map(. as $row | $cols | map($row[.])) as $rows | $cols, $rows[] | @csv' > pes.csv
```

The problem is that this file has sized up to more than 2GB. I'm studying to apply streaming but still can not understand how to use it. Any help, please? Many thanks.

Update, I tried this code and I can stream the file output:

```
cat pelias_minify.json | jq -cn --stream 'fromstream(0|truncate_stream(inputs)) | {lat: ._source.center_point.lat, lon: ._source.center_point.lon, address: ._source.name.default}'
```

Ouput:

```
{"center_point":{"lon":106.66307,"lat":10.959882},"name":{"default":"375/20 Bùi Quốc Khánh, Chánh Nghĩa, Bình Dương, Việt Nam"}}
{"center_point":{"lon":106.66307,"lat":10.959882},"name":{"default":"375/20 Bùi Quốc Khánh, Chánh Nghĩa, Bình Dương, Việt Nam"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As peak suggests, your output doesn't require the streaming parser of `jq` to be invoked. If you can efficiently filter out the required fields alone for the CSV output, you should be fine, i.e.

```
jq -r -cn '["address","lat","lon"], (inputs | [._source.name.default,._source.center_point.lat,._source.center_point.lon]) | @csv'
```

Comment: Many thanks, is there any way to study jq rather than the manual doc? I found it does not help much.

Comment: The jq Cookbook has lots of useful examples - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook, along with the FAQ - https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/FAQ

Comment: Hi, I want to make a generic approach which means I will convert all keys and values to csv. I'm trying to find a way for flatten the object.

Answer (score 2):

Since the input file is just a stream of JSON entities, and since it seems each output row depends only on one of these, you can avoid memory issues most simply by NOT using the -s command-line option, and adapting your jq program accordingly. There should be no need to use the —stream option.